# Cocoapods - Overview & Concept

Tags: ios, xcode, bitbucket, cocoapods

I'm attempting to configure my first CocoaPods repository using BitBucket and struggling with what is possibly something very basic.

On my local machine I've created a root directory called 'CocoaPods' and with this directory I've created an Xcode project called 'HelloWorld' and also a HelloWorld.podspec. If I'm understanding things correctly the root directory will contain all my *.podspec files and these will then point to the relevant files/projects, Question 1 is this structure / concept correct?

This directory is then synced with my BitBucket account that has a repository called CocoaPods, I've then added the repository using :

```
pod repo add Cocoapods https://bitbucket.org/username/CocoaPods.git
```

At this point I've not been able to test this because when I issue the following:

```
pod spec lint HelloWorld.podspec
```

The pod spec I've created does not pass validation:

```
-> HelloWorld (1.0.0)
    - WARN  | The summary is not meaningful.
    - WARN  | The description is shorter than the summary.
    - ERROR | [iOS] The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
    - WARN  | [iOS] Unable to find a license file

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation.
```

The HelloWorld.podspec file is :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "HelloWorld"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "A short description of the hello world pod"
  s.description  = "Stuff to describe the app here"
  s.homepage     = "https://www.mywebsite-it.co.uk"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author       = { "a18041967" => "myemail@somedomain.co.uk" }
  s.source       = { :git => "git@bitbucket.org:myusername/cocoapods.git", :tag => "v1.0.0" }
  s.source_files = "HelloWorld/*"
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.ios.deployment_target = "6.0"
  s.platform = :ios, "6.0"
end
```

Question 2, My understanding is that the s.source_files are relative to the location of the podspec file, in the above example there's a directory called HelloWorld which contains all the standard Xcode project files.

All the files have been pushed the remote origin and the structure on bitbucket is CocoaPods /HelloWorld/HelloWorld/ the podspec file is in CocoaPods and the Xcode project file is in CocoaPods /HelloWorld/ and all other project files in CocoaPods/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/

Comment: did you find an answer for this ?